# Multiple Check box input to text area - add text - remove text from text area

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function moveNumbers(num) { 
var txt=document.getElementById("result").value; 
txt=txt + num; 
document.getElementById("result").value=txt; 
} 
</script>

<textarea id="result" name="image_id" rows="8" cols="11" readonly>

</textarea>
<tr>

<?php
$path = "photos/";
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder");
echo "<table height='500px'width='800px'align='center'border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {

if($file == "index.php")
continue;
if($file == ".")
continue;
if($file == "..")
continue;
{
echo ($x % 6 == 0) ? "</tr><tr>" : "";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='add' value='$file'             
onclick='moveNumbers(this.value)'>
<img src='photos/$file'alt='$file' style='height:auto;width:50%;'alt='$file'>
<br>
$file
</td>";
$x++;
}
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
closedir($dir_handle);
 ?>
```

Hi all, PHP finds image files and displays them with check boxes next to them. I'm having trouble with the check boxes input to text area. When checked it adds text then when you uncheck it adds the same text again. I'm trying to do the following: Checked -> Add text, Uncheck the same check box -> Remove text. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to arbitrarily add text that is not known in advance and then later remove it, you'll need to either keep a list of items that have been added and regenerate the result each time, or do a search/replace operation to remove it.  I think keeping the list is easier:

```
var itemsAdded = Array();

function moveNumbers(text) { 
   var i = itemsAdded.indexOf(text)
   if ( i >= 0) { 
       itemsAdded.splice(i,1); 
   } else {
       itemsAdded.push(text);
   }
   document.getElementById("result").value=itemsAdded.join(" "); //if you want each on a separate line, use "\n" instead of " "
}
```

Comment: Hi Joe, Reason for no id for check boxes is they are made on the fly via PHP. PHP searches directory displays images with check box next to them.. Cheers

Comment: reworked it to not use the id, just delete the first occurrance of the value.  Should work fine as long as no 2 checkboxes have the same value.

Comment: aww damn still can't get it to work? doing something wrong I think?

Comment: My bad, fat fingers got me again.  Corrected now, and here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LAcgE/)

Comment: Your jsFiddle and your answer don't match; just saying.

Comment: @fred other than the fiddle having some extra jQuery to generate the checkboxes, what's different?

Comment: For some reason, I tried it out and it didn't work unless I added the extra piece of code that is below `document.getElementById("result").value=itemsAdded.join(" ");`

Comment: that's the last line in the moveNumbers function, is it not displaying when you view my answer?   Sometimes markdown escapes me, so I may have messed something up there.  I see you fixed it for me, thank you

Comment: @Joe Wait, my bad. Sorry I take that back. I think what happened is that I copied your last edit and I didn't see that you forgot to indent the last line of code `}`. It works now and I edited it just a few minutes for you.

Comment: Woo Hoo! fantastic, it works like a charm, I have been straggling with this for hours! Thanks Joe for the fix and thanks Fred for a test result. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

After considering why someone would want to do this, it occurred to me that you might be trying to present the user with a dynamically generated list of checkboxes, and then determine server-side which boxes were checked.

If that is what you are working on, you may find it useful to receive the list back as a PHP array.
To get that, simply change the name attribute of your dynamically generated checkboxes to end in `[]`
I tested using this code:

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
                $("form").append("<input type='checkbox' name='add[]' value='img_id" + i + "'>Checkbox " + i + "</input><br/>") 
            }
        });
    </script>
    <form id='selection'  action='info.php' method='POST'>
        <input type="submit" /><br />
    </form>
```

After checking boxes 0,4, 6-8, and clicking submit,  `$_POST` in the info.php script had this value (as returned by `print_r($_POST);`:

```
Array
(
    [add] => Array
        (
            [0] => img_id0
            [1] => img_id4
            [2] => img_id6
            [3] => img_id7
            [4] => img_id8
        )
)
```

Comment: Yep I think dynamic was the word missing from my original question it probably makes more sense even to me now! I'll check it out, Cheers Joe.